# Centering images without "left: X px;" because it isn't responsive on smaller devices

Tags: html, css

I wanted to center the social media images and bunch them together. I figured I can move it over to the right by using `right: 100px;`, but it won't stay relative to page size. If I scale my page to mobile size, it doesn't stay centered as the header does.

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zachary300/tpwxfghn/19/) might make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Set the display property on "row" to flex and use "justify-content" to position the elements in center horizontally. You can remove relative positioning on the ".social" elements.

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/VH659W4/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.column {    
    z-index: 100;
}
.row {
    display: flex;    
    z-index: 100;    
    justify-content: center;
}
.social {    
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 36px;
    z-index: 100;    
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>
            DJ JUMO
        </title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/djjumo/" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/N7dFXZ4/instagram.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/s3VrxZJ/twitter.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/djjumo" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/prCyYw3/snapchat.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/5Y77Bcm/facebook.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <img id="header" src="https://i.ibb.co/gdHS8by/header.png" alt="logo">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have one more question. The images of social media are spaced out and I want to bunch them up together, I can't find a way to do this

Comment: Yes, fixed it. On .social{ } css selector, change the width from 50% to let's say 35px, then there would be no gap between the social media images. You can increase or decrease this width as per your requirement. Along with that, I suggest add your original code in your question.